# Magento 2 How to add new address in 'customer_address_entity' from helper?

Tags: magento2, customer, eav, customer-address, helper

I am using helper data function to add the new address in `customer_address_entity` but it is not working. code as below :

```
<?php

namespace Name\Module\Helper;

use \Magento\Framework\App\Helper\AbstractHelper;

class Data extends AbstractHelper
{
    protected $addressDataFactory;
    protected $addressRepository; 

    public function __construct(
       \Magento\Customer\Api\Data\AddressInterface $addressDataFactory,
       \Magento\Customer\Api\AddressRepositoryInterface $addressRepository
   ) {
        $this->addressDataFactory = $addressDataFactory;
        $this->addressRepository = $addressRepository;  
    }
    public function assignAddressToCustomer($location,$customer)
    {
        $address = $this->addressDataFactory;

        $address->setFirstname($customer->getData('firstname'))
        ->setLastname($customer->getData('lastname'))
        ->setCustomerId($customer->getData('entity_id'))

        ->setCountryId($location->getData('country_id'))            
        ->setRegionId($location->getData('region_id'))
            //->setRegion($location->getData('region'))
        ->setCity($location->getData('city'))
        ->setPostcode($location->getData('postcode'))            
        ->setStreet(array($location->getData('street')))           
        ->setTelephone($location->getData('telephone'))
        ->setData('save_in_address_book', '1');

        try{
          $this->addressRepository->save($address);                 
      }catch (Exception $e) {
        Zend_Debug::dump($e->getMessage());
    }

    return;
}
}
```

It goes in try section, but in the database, there is no update. 
Is there something missing?

i am trying but it gives error as below :

it gives error in apache log "PHP Fatal error:

```
Uncaught Exception: User Error: Some transactions have not been committed or rolled back in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\M2\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\DB\\Adapter\\Pdo\\Mysql.php on line 3955 in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\M2\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\App\\ErrorHandler.php:61\nStack trace:\n#0 [internal function]: Magento\\Framework\\App\\ErrorHandler->handler(256, 'Some transactio...', 'C:\\\\xampp\\\\htdocs...', 3955, Array)\n#1 C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\M2\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\DB\\Adapter\\Pdo\\Mysql.php(3955): trigger_error('Some transactio...', 256)\n#2 [internal function]: Magento\\Framework\\DB\\Adapter\\Pdo\\Mysql->__destruct()\n#3 {main}\n  thrown in C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\M2\\vendor\\magento\\framework\\App\\ErrorHandler.php on line 61, referer: http://127.0.0.1/M2/admin/customer/index/new/key/1f129dbde8115d6f0c4789e039353302bbf9c039d78881f155a623a083f49d70/"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I changed into the helper function and its working now. I found the solution as below in hlper function:

```
public function assignAddressToCustomer($location,$customer) {
    $defaultAddress = $this->addressFactory->create();                      
    $defaultAddress->setData('street', $location->getData('street'));
    $defaultAddress->setData('city', $location->getData('city'));
    $defaultAddress->setData('country_id', $location->getData('country_id'));
    $defaultAddress->setData('postcode', $location->getData('postcode'));
    $defaultAddress->setData('region', $location->getData('region'));
    $defaultAddress->setData('region_id', $location->getData('region_id'));
    $defaultAddress->setData('telephone', $location->getData('telephone'));
    $defaultAddress->setData('fax', $location->getData('fax'));
    $defaultAddress->setData('company', $location->getData('company'));
    $defaultAddress->setData('firstname', $customer->getData('firstname'));
    $defaultAddress->setData('lastname', $customer->getData('lastname'));
    $defaultAddressObj = $defaultAddress->getDataModel();
    $defaultAddressObj->setCustomAttribute('custom_id', $location->getData('custom_id'));
    $defaultAddress->updateData($defaultAddressObj);      
    $defaultAddress->save();
    return;
}
```

Also we need to add dependency for addressFactory as below:

```
\Magento\Customer\Model\AddressFactory $addressFactory
```